# Get duplicate rows count

Tags: php, mysql

Following is my query which I am using to import data from csv file and ignore only those rows (for avoiding duplication) which already exists in the database. Now what I am trying to get is only the count of those rows which gets ignored as they already exist in the DB, kindly let me know how can I get this count ?

```
$con->query("LOAD DATA Local INFILE 'CSVFILEPATH' IGNORE INTO TABLE DUPLICATES FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES")
```

Comment: A simple calculation: (data lines count in csv) -  (rows count in table)

Comment: I did it like this : `$file_read = file($csv_name, FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES); $file_read_count = count($file_read);`

Comment: It is a little unclear, but do is it OK to load the CSV file into a table before finding the duplicates?

Comment: @MatsKindahl What I am doing is getting firstly the total number of rows of uploaded file and then getting how many rows gets affected by `mysqli_affected_rows()` and then subtracting it from the total gives me what i want....

Answer (score 0):

Only one solution I see is to count records in table and compare with records count in file.

Simple query to count number of records in table:

```
$q = $conn->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM DUPLICATES");
$f = $q->fetch();
$linesInTable = $f['cnt'];
```

To count number of lines in file you can use shell command.

Linux:

```
$linesInFile = trim( `cat 'CSVFILEPATH'|wc -l` );
```

Windows:

```
$linesInFile = trim( `Find /V /C "" < CSVFILEPATH` );
```

Now calculate duplicated records:

```
$duplicatedLines = $linesInFile - $linesInTable;
```

Answer (score -1):

To count total unique rows in table you can use the SQL Query

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT column_name) FROM table_name;
```